# Facebook API 2.6 Page Like Count

Tags: facebook-graph-api

With the recent release of 2.6 I'm now getting a list of page likes when I hit the endpoint of "/facebook?fields=likes,id,name" where in 2.5 and before it would be a count. I'm not seeing any documentation of this change and I don't know how to get a count of likes anymore.

If I just count the list of likes it doesn't seem to be matching up to the number of likes the page actually has when I look at it directly on Facebook.

Has anyone come across this yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

v2.6 of the Graph API moved some things around to keeps their likes consistent across object types. You can use fan_count as the new likes counter.

Don't forget to include fan_count in your fields request.

Yeah, i know... Facebook really loves backwards compatility... *cough*